# SSIS input column [Column] and reference column named [Column] have incompatible data types in server alone

Tags: c#-4.0, ssis

My scenario is I upload an excel and take a column [ColumnExcel] in excel which is of type DT_WSTR and compare lookup that with a DB2 field[ColumnDB2] which is of type CHAR(9). I convert the DT_WSTR into DT_STR type and do the lookup. I execute this package via C# code and works perfectly fine in my local machine but it doesn't work and gives an error

```
"input column [ColumnExcelConverted] and reference column named [ColumnDB2] have incompatible data types."
```

in production machine.

1) My system has BIDS 2008 but in production it does not have BIDS but has Execute package utility of SQL server 2008 R2.
2) Also the driver in my system is IBM DB2 ODBC driver 8.01 while in production it is IBM DB2 ODBC driver 9.01.

What could be the problem and solution. I am still unable to find the exact cause.

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of the C# code? Did you try to cast DT_STR to DT_WSTR?

Comment: No I did not try that. Is there a way to cast while performing lookup?

Comment: With SSIS, there are many ways. Can you post a screen shot of your data flow?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely your differing versions of your ODBC driver.